# Calling an associated function in a struct of a dynamically loaded library in Rust

Tags: rust, dylib

I have setup the following infrastructure using rust-embed:

#### Crate A:

- Builds a `dylib` (`.so` file) which uses a derive macro to load files at compile time to a struct.

```
#[derive(RustEmbed)]
#[folder = "./src"]
struct Asset;
```

Code and more documentation is here: https://github.com/pyrossh/rust-embed#documentation

In this case it loads all the files within `./src` of that crate.

#### Crate B:

- Loads the built `.so` file from crate A using `libloading` with the following type: `type LoadAssetFunc = fn() -> Asset;`
- Should be able to call `Asset::get` (`get` is defined in the `RustEmbed` derive macro)

However even if I am returning `Asset` within a struct or a `Box` it'll use the `./src` files within the current crate, so it is using the struct of `Asset` within Crate B which also uses the derive macro and it is not using the struct of `Asset` within Crate A which loaded the files within that crate. How can I make sure it is using `Asset` of Crate A and not B?

Comment: Have you tried this? `#[folder = "$CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR/src"]`. or if you are using workspaces, this? `#[folder = "$CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR/../crate-a/src"]`

Comment: I solved it by using the `include_dir` crate instead as it returns a `static` `Dir` which makes it easier to use in my case.